# Listview from ArrayList class

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to figure out how to display the items of an ArrayList which I have stored in a separate class into a ListView. I've been looking it up all day but the problem is that I can't find something like this specifically in which I had created a different class where I stored the ArrayList. It's a task I got for an internship and they asked me to use a local database or hardcode it so I chose to hardcode it.

```
import com.mircea.bookapp.Book;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Books
{
    private ArrayList<Book> booklist;

    public Books()
    {
        booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();

        booklist.add(new Book("In Search of Lost Time", "Marcel Proust", 1913, "Modernist"));
        booklist.add(new Book("Ulysses", "James Joyce", 1922, "Modernist novel"));
        booklist.add(new Book("Don Quixote", "Miguel de Cervantes", 1612, "Novel"));
        booklist.add(new Book("The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald", 1925, "Tragedy"));
        booklist.add(new Book("One Hundred Years Of Solitude", "Gabriel Garcia Marquez", 1967, "Magic realism"));
    }

    public Book getBook(int index)
    {
        return this.booklist.get(index);
    }
}
```

This is the code from the Class from which I wanna get the info for the ListView.

Answer (score 2):

In your MainActivity onCreate method:

```
ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<>();
//here You have to load all books from Books class as a string to this array
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, books);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To resources/layouts add this file. (here You can modify row style in ListView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
```

You can also use a custom style, e.g.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, books);
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern / UI widget you're looking for is called RecyclerView. This is the standard way to show a list of items as it has some nice performance optimizations to re-use inflated layouts.

d.android.com has a nice guide on how to achieve what you want here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

The key thing to implement is the adapter methods, `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemCount` which will call into your Books class to get the total number of Books and access each Book to bind the view to. Modified from this example: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    private Books books;

    public MyAdapter(Books books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
        ViewGroup parent,
        int viewType
    ) {
        return new MyViewHolder(parent); // you need to implement this class!
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(books.getBook(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return books.getBookCount();
    }
}
```